# PHP PDO Query for Event Listing

Tags: php, mysql, list, pdo, fetch

i'm working on a events project and i want to show my users' events which they've hosted in their profile pages, but i got stuck on with listing the events.

The other things are working well.

here are the codes:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
$id = intval($_GET["id"]);
if(!empty($id)) {

try {
$pq = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id";
$pq_check = $db->prepare($pq);
$pq_check->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$pq_check->execute();
$ac = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
} 
catch(PDOException $e) { $log->logError($e." - ".basename(__FILE__));
}


// i'm fetching the user info and showing them name age gender exc. , no problem with here


echo "Events That User Hosted :\n";

// here is the place i have problem

$eq = "SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `host_id` = :id";
$eq_check = $db->prepare($eq);
$eq_check->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$eq_check->execute();
$foo = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
if(!empty($foo)) {
$_loader = true;
$fetch = $eq_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

while($fetch = $eq_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){ 
if ($fetch == NULL ) {
break;
}

$event_id = $fetch['event_id'];
$event_name = $fetch['event_name'];
$link = "https://www.mywebsite.com/e/$event_id";

echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$link\"><li>$event_name</li></a>";

} 

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the actual *problem* you are having? SQL Error, not the data you expected?

Comment: not giving any errors but not printing out also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you fetch the first row of the result set and then you throw it away:

```
if(!empty($foo)) {
  $_loader = true;
  $fetch = $eq_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

/* above you have fetched the first row but that value gets overwritten
   directly after that: */

while ($fetch = $eq_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 

/* $fetch now contains the second row of the result set, if it exists... */
```

**Edit:** I would clean up the code, add error handling and see what happens:

```
try
{
  $eq = "SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `host_id` = :id";
  $eq_check = $db->prepare($eq);
  $eq_check->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $eq_check->execute();

  while($fetch = $eq_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
  { 
    $_loader = true;

    $event_id = $fetch['event_id'];
    $event_name = $fetch['event_name'];
    $link = "https://www.mywebsite.com/e/$event_id";

    echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$link\"><li>$event_name</li></a>";
  }
} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  $log->logError($e." - ".basename(__FILE__));
}
```

Comment: Additionally: `while($fetch = $eq_check->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){ 
if ($fetch == NULL ) {
break;
}` - the if is pointless.

Comment: yes i know, because of that i imported a dummy content for the first event, but there are other events after that, but i can't list them too..

Comment: @mrmryb Completely true, I would also say that the second query `$foo = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();` is unnecessary, you can start fetching rows immediately after the `execute` statement.

Comment: i don't think its pointless because i think that without that it will get into infinite loop

Comment: @CastielMartin The while loop you are using will stop after there are no more rows to be fetched from the database because the condition will evaluate to false. The break will never be called because the while loop wont execute once $fetch is null.

Comment: okay thanks for that information but do you see any reason that why i can't list the events.